# Mic5158 does not regulate

Tags: mosfet-driver, ldo

Refering to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/218854/vreg-with-mic5156-why-a-so-high-drop-out-voltage) post, I changed mic5156 to mic5158 ([datasheet](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mic5156.pdf)) and
[this](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/139f/0900766b8139f5f9.pdf) mos.

I wired it several times as the datasheet shows but I can't get any regulated
voltage.
In order to understand what happens, I removed the mos and put a potentiometer
instead of the divider. The result is (IMHO) what it should: The gate voltage is
maximum when the divider is below the 1.235V reference voltage the goes to 
"nearly zero" (in fact around 1 v) when the divider is above 1.235V.

Yellow: divider

Green: Vcp

Orange: Vgate

[image]

Then, I rebuild the circuit with the mos and did the following measurement:

Yellow: divider

Green: Vcp

Orange: Vgate

Light blue: Vgs

Starting with a 1A load, I raised it until 10A.

Some observations:

- The output voltage goes from "too high" to "too low". The voltage is correct only when on marker 2 in the below capture.
- The pump voltage falls to 0v on marker 1.

[image]

I definitely don't understand what happen.
Did I do a wrong choice with the mos?
Should I work around capacitors of the charge pump?
Is there a reason why the gate voltage in first test goes to "nearly 0v"
and not 0v?
Is it a regular behaviour that the charge pump voltage goes to 0? I supposed that It should stay always high, only the Vgs changes but may be I"m wrong.

A lot of interrogations...

[update]

Schematic:

[image]

Breadboard:

[image]

[Update]

I changed MOS for IRF610 ([datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91023/91023.pdf)) and... It works! The specs does not fit my needs but the voltage is regulated with. Still wonder which characteristic makes the original mos unsuitable.

Comment: Since you are not sure you wire it correctly... why don't you post a schematic for us?

Comment: Well, I'm 99% sure it is wired as in the datasheet. But as it is on a breadboard for evaluation purpose, I don't have any computer automated checking of the wiring. (It is the 1% left). I'll change the text to avoid confusion. I can send you a picture if you want but I'm not sure it is really readable

Comment: Your question is in the top 90 percent for this board. Add a schematic, snap a pic and you get to the top 99%...

Comment: Done. Did my best to make the breadboard understandable! ;)

Comment: I do not really have time right now, but your question looks great. I will hopefully have a look tomorrow.

Comment: The 1V gate voltage is normal (cfr. row 9, table on page 4). Your cp looks good, before and after the drop it is in spec as per the same table. I do not understand why you say it drops to zero, it seems ~10V to me, marker 2 is out of screen apparently. What about Vout? And with Vgain you perhaps mean Vgate? Include Vgate and Vload=Vsource instead of Vgain and Vgs

Comment: I always felt that Micrel made garbage regulators. Every one I've ever had had terrible noise immunity and transient response to load changes. Go with something more reliable like Linear Tech or TI. Just my two cents.

Comment: @vladimirCravero : 10v -> You're right. Marker is in fact marker 1,VGain is Vgate. I fixed the text. Vout is a multiple of Vdivider (yellow), It varies from ~6.5v to ~5.5V while it should be regulated to 6v.

Comment: I changes MOS for IRF610 ([datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91023/91023.pdf)) and... It works! The specs does not fit my needs but the voltage is regulated. Still wonder which characteristic makes the original mos unsuitable.

Comment: @bss36504: any suggestion for part number?

Comment: @Julien Not anything specific, just look at one of the "Higher end" companies (LT, TI, Maxim). Maybe now that Microchip owns Micrel they will suck less, but I've never really loved Microchip either. Too bad they bought Atmel...Anyway, that second transistor has a much lower RDS_on, which is the first thing I noticed. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is a bit stupid: le MOS was... dead. Lot of time lost.

Comment: Such things happen. You have now learned to look for them sooner.